# How can I import a workspace as a dependency in another go repository?

Tags: go

I have a go multiple workspace project whose structure is:

```
apps/go.mod
go.work
```

The project includes a submodule `apps` and its `go.work` file has:

```
go 1.180
use (
./apps
)
```

I have another go project (separate repository) wants to import this `app` submodule as a library, below is `go.mod`:

```
module xxxx

go 1.18

require (
    github.com/zhaoyi0113/test-go-module v0.0.3 // indirect
)
```

then I have below code:

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/zhaoyi0113/test-go-module/apps/logger"
)

func main() {
    logger.Test()
}
```

It fails to compile with the error:

```
main.go:7:2: no required module provides package github.com/zhaoyi0113/test-go-module/apps/logger; to add it:
        go get github.com/zhaoyi0113/test-go-module/apps/logger
```

How can I import the submodule from the multiple workspaces project?

Comment: `I have another go project`, where did you place this project? It should be placed in the directory that holds the `go.work` file or its subdirectory. And please note that the `go.work` file does not belong to the `apps` module.

Comment: `How can I import a workspace as a dependency in a go project?` Please note that a workspace is never imported as a dependency. See this tutorial: https://go.dev/doc/tutorial/workspaces

Comment: The other place is a separate repo

Comment: if I can't use workspace, is there anyother way for me to import a sub folder from a dependency?

Comment: You can use workspace. See the tutorial to understand how workspace work first.

Comment: There are no "submodules", only modules. You cannot import modules at all, only packages can be imported. Please read and follow go.dev/doc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot import a workspace.

Here's the current situation:

There is a module at `github.com/zhaoyi0113/test-go-module/apps` which [declares its module path](https://github.com/zhaoyi0113/test-go-module/blob/58f8cf8510a39af1fda5a8b3edd8a74a9318ca49/apps/go.mod#L1) as `github.com/zhaoyi0113/test-go-module`.  This module is not useable because the actual path to the module and the declared path do not match (notice that `/apps` is missing in one of the paths).

The xxxx module requires `github.com/zhaoyi0113/test-go-module`, but there there is no module found at the path. It's in the `apps` subdirectory as noted in the previous paragraph.

There are two possible fixes depending on where you want to place the module.

If you want to keep imported go.mod in [it's current directory](https://github.com/zhaoyi0113/test-go-module/tree/58f8cf8510a39af1fda5a8b3edd8a74a9318ca49/apps) then update the module paths to include `apps`:

go.mod for imported module:

```
module github.com/zhaoyi0113/test-go-module/apps
go 1.19
```

go.mod for importing module:

```
module xxxx
go 1.18
require (
    github.com/zhaoyi0113/test-go-module/apps v0.0.3 // indirect
)
```

The second and conventional option
is to place the go.mod at the root of the project and put the go.work file outside of the project. To make this work, move go.mod to the root of the project ([as it was in the initial commit](https://github.com/zhaoyi0113/test-go-module/tree/737ee112b560722dcf1d2bc504028267ce0e31a5)) and move go.work somewhere else.  No changes are required to the importing module.